# dotNET COM Initialization Issues

Tags: .net, .net-core, com

I have a legacy application using several .NET 6 COM components. Depending on the load order of the COM components, certain ones will fail to load with an error (0x800080A5).

I've uploaded an example project that will cause the issue [here](https://github.com/william-airshipvms/com_issue).

The gist is that there are two COM servers, project 1 and project 2. If project 2 has certain dependencies (in this example `CoreWCF.WebHttp`), and is loaded after project 1, then it will result in this error. It seems as if there is some initialization that occurs that is only triggered one time.

If the load order is reversed, so that project 2 is loaded before project 1, then everything will load fine.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/host-error-codes.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your exe with a tool such as [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview), you will see this output:

```
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App' is not present in the previously loaded runtime.
```

It's because project ComProject2 implicitely requires the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` framework because of the dependency on the `CoreWCF.WebHttp` package.

For some reason, the .NET core loader cannot load an additional framework automatically in this COM scenario (the exe is not a .NET Core app). But you can [configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/) it, this is described with more details here: [Framework-dependent Deployment Model](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/main/documentation/specs/runtime-configuration-file.md#framework-dependent-deployment-model)

There are multiple ways of fixing it. One solution is, *at deployment time*, to copy the content of the generated `ComProject2.runtimeconfig.json` file into `ComProject1.runtimeconfig.json`, to force the first component to load the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App framework, so it content should be this:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net6.0",
    "rollForward": "LatestMinor",
    "frameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
        "version": "6.0.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
        "version": "6.0.0"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Another solution is, as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/#runtimeconfigjson), to create a file named `runtimeconfig.template.json` at ComProject1's root with a content like this:

```
{
  "frameworks": [
    {
      "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
      "version": "6.0.0"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

and it will be merged, at build time (requires a rebuild the first time), into `ComProject1.runtimeconfig.json`.

Comment: A small note, if using a `runtimeconfig.template.json` it may cause issues when registering with regsvr32 if the existing framework has a `Framework` entry, and you are merging in a `Frameworks` entry. The merging doesn't automatically combine these two, so it leaves you with both nodes in the json.