# 2 projectname.comhost.dll in same build directory possible?

Tags: c#, mfc, com-interop, regsvr32, com-interface

I have a legacy *32bit-MFC-Application* which uses *COleDispatchDriver* mechanism to use a c# dll made with net7.0 in VSCode.

After build command of c# dll, there is *projName.dll* , *projName.comhost.dll* (because i used attributes in *.cs files to make it come visible, and set ItemProperties in *.csproj)

Then *projName.comhost.dll* was sucessfully registred with regsvr for 32bit dlls.

So the Clsid and pathToComhost dll aswell as the ProgId of the dll are in the registry then.

The MFC-Proj is using a headerfile with a wrapperclass which allows me to "use" this *projName.dll*

So this is working, no problem with that.

But, now i have a new Testcase which does not work and i don't understand why.

TestCase:

*Proj1: Test1c#.dll ComVisible*

*Proj2: Test2c#.dll ComVisible*

Proj1: has <ProjectReference Include="..\*Test2c#*\*Test2c#*.csproj" />

then i do the build:

dotnet publish $pathTo*Test1c#*Csproj -c Release -r win-x86 --no-self-contained /p:DebugType=None /p:DebugSymbols=false

Result:

The build directory contains *Test1c#.comhost.dll and Test2c#.comhost.dll.*

As before i go on and  use regsvr to register, *Test1c#.comhost.dll this works,*

but when using regsvr with *Test2c#.comhost.dll it fails with error* 0x80008093. (message was: loading comhost dll was possible but call to DllRegisterServer failed)

Now im stuck and trying to understand what happens.

Then i copied *Test2c#*.runtimeconfig.json

from the builddirectory of the Test2 project into the publish directory of *Test1c#.dll to see if regsvr can now successfully call its DllRegisterServer.*

Result: success, no error message.

But calling to

`bResult = objTestclass.CreateDispatch(L"Test2c#.Test");`

in the mfc application fails aswell. (Test1c#dll is still working)

Any hints on that? Is this even a supported scenario?

Comment: Difficult to say w/o a reproducing project. That may be a deployment issue around json file, you can have a look at this for ideas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77449138/dotnet-com-initialization-issues/77451296#77451296